# Is there a probability distribution with infinitely many parameters?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For example,
Poisson distribution has one parameter,
the Binomial distribution has two parameters. But is there a distribution with infinitely many parameters? Or, can we define the multinomial distribution with infinitely many parameters, e.g. $Mult_\infty(n, \vec{p})$, where $\vec{p}$ is an infinitely large vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Any non-negative integrable (with non-zero integral) function can be scaled to be a probability distribution. We could take for example the family of functions of the form

$$\frac{1}{\int_0^1 e^{f(t)} dt} e^{f(x)}, 0\leq x \leq 1$$

where $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$. This is parametrized by the coefficients $a_n$. Restrict them to be bounded so that it converges all right.